# Is there a function for nearest power of 2 in Mathematica like nextpow2 in MATLAB?

Tags: functions, binary

I am looking for something like `nextpow2` in MATLAB like [this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/nextpow2.html):

> `P = nextpow2(A)` returns the exponents for the smallest powers of two that satisfy $2^P\geq\left|A\right|$.

Comment: `Ceiling[Log[2, #]] &`

Comment: For integers there is `IntegerLength[A, 2]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this?

```
nextpow2[a_] := Ceiling @ Log[2, Abs @ a];
```

or

```
nextpow2[a_] := Ceiling[RealExponent[a, 2]]
```

---

The same thing in a different style:

```
f1 = Ceiling @* Log2 @* Abs;  (* v10 syntax *)
```

Or:

```
f2 = ⌈Log2 @ Abs @ #⌉ &;
```

A plot:

```
Plot[f2[x], {x, -10, 10}, Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thank you! I learned something from you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do you know if the v10 syntax is documented anywhere? Searching for `@*` in the documentation turns up nothing.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, it is: [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html).  See also [`RightComposition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html).  (I suppose the search failed because both `@` and `*` are simple wildcards.)

Comment: Re "v10 syntax": is it just the shortcut notation `@*` that was added in *Mathematica* 10*? Note that `Composition` dates to version 2.0.

Comment: @murray. Yes, it's just the infix notation that was added in *V10*

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I have been using this for some time and never told you thank you :) So here it is Thank you Mr. Wizard

Comment: @jason You're welcome for my part in this, and thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 6):

You have a good answer already, but I'll mention the following since it may be useful in the future.

Many built-in functions are written in MATLAB and can be viewed, in this case `edit nextpow2.m` brings up the source for this function, which can be used as a starting point to implement in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same, but very closely related is [`BitLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BitLength.html).

> `BitLength[n]` gives the number of binary bits necessary to represent the integer `n`.
>
> For positive `n`, `BitLength[n]` is effectively an efficient version of `Floor[Log[2,n]]+1`.
>
> For negative `n`, it is equivalent to `BitLength[BitNot[n]]`

When is it not equivalent to `nextpow2`?

- It works for integers only.
- When the argument is positive and an integer power of 2, the result of `BitLength` will be one greater than that of `nextpow2`.